# Find a bound for the absolute error on the interval

Tags: numerical-methods

Find a bound for the absolute error on the interval $[x_{0}, x_{n}]$

$f(x) =  cos(x)+sin(x)$

for $x_{0}=0, x_{1} = .25, x_{2} = .5, x_{3} = 1, n = 3$

So using the Lagrange error bound formula:
$ \frac{cos(\xi) + sin(\xi)}{4!} x(x-.25)(x-.5)(x-1)$

My answer for the error bound is $1.55x10^{-3}$

The book's answer for the error bound is $1.59x10^{-3}$

I don't know where I am going wrong.

Comment: Did you use that $\cos(x)+\sin(x)=\sqrt{2}\sin(x+\frac\pi4)$? Please add details on how you found your bound, it is difficult to suggest alternatives without that.

Comment: I used just cos(x)+sin(x).

Comment: I am hoping someone just does the problem and see where I diverge. I used the mean value theorem for x(x-.25)(x-.5)(x-1). For the trig function, I plug in 1.